# react-router: passing props to a component that is rendered with <Link />

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm using react-router's `<Link />` so that when a user clicks the link, `myComponent` is rendered.

My question is, how can I pass props into the `myComponent` from the `Navigation` component? This doesn't work, but I'm trying to pass a `element.name` prop from `Navigation` to `myComponent`.

```
class Navigation extends Component {
  const items = store.getState().items.map((element, index) =>
    <Link to={element.id} name={element.name}> element.id </Link>
  )

  render() {
    return (
      {items}
    )
  }
}
```

Here's the route setup & component setup:

```
<Route path=":id" component={myComponent} />

// I'd like to pass in props to be used here from the Navigation component, for example, a name prop passed through <Link />

class myCompnent extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p> hello {this.props.name} </p>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[react-router Link](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/latest/docs/API.md#link)

I don't think there is a way to pass props from <Link> to the component, But using 'query' params of Link can pass something with the path, it will be add on the path as query like: ?name=jack&aa=bb

```
<Link to={element.id} query={{ name: element.name }}>{element.id}</Link>
```

and get it from this.props.location.query in component

```
componentDidMount: function () {
    var query = this.props.location.query;
    if ( query && query.name ) {
        this.setState({
            name: name
        });
    } 
}

// in render
<p> hello {this.state.name} </p>
```

Comment: I see, but it wouldn't be appropriate to pass down an entire object as a prop like that right? say `{name: "bob", age: 55, location: "California"}`

If an entire object from the global store can't be passed into the component, how does the component get access to app state?

Comment: One way I am using is fetching these informations in the wrapper App Component, and passing them with props.  Link tag is actually an <a> tag, it's not designed for passing these states to components.

Comment: I guess my problem is that I don't understand how a component gets access to a specific piece of data when its rendered via <Link />

Say I click on a link to a user's profile, well I would have to pass in the user profile's data as props. How do I do that?

Must I only pass in the profile name (attached as param)? and use store.getState().users to match up the param and data object of the user? This seems like a long a tedious way to access user profile data.

Comment: I think it's better that the myCompnent fetch user data from store, with the params :id to get the exact one.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is pass the `props` by appending them to the Component link in Parent Component and get them using `componentWillReceiveProps` method in child component.

For Example :

Parent Component

```
<Link to {`element.id/{$element.name}`}>{element.id}</Link>
```

Child Component

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.value !== this.props.value) {
        console.log(this.props); //Here you can fetch the props which you have passed
    }
}
```